# How can I login to Skype with a username (not phone number or email)

Tags: skype

On the Skype app, I can't login to my account with my usual Skype credentials. It keeps telling me "please enter your phone number or your email address".

I can login to the desktop version just fine. I don't want to make a new or separate account for the mobile version, I just want to log in with my existing account.